# Are there any performance drawbacks to using 'do nothing' default event handlers?

Tags: c#, performance, event-handling

Let's say I have a collection of thousands of objects, all of which implement the following:

```
public event EventHandler StatusChanged = (s,e) => {};
private void ChangeStatus()
{
  StatusChanged(this, new EventArgs());
}
```

If no handlers are subscribed to that event for each object, does using the no-op event handler provide any performance drawbacks?  Or is the CLR smart enough to ignore it?  Or am I better off checking for a `StatusChanged` handler before firing the event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the CLR is not really smart enough to ignore it but the difference should be negligible in most cases.

A method call is not a big deal and is unlikely to have a meaningful impact on the performance of your application.

Comment: What if I had say 5000 objects potentially firing the event simultaneously?  Would that have any noticeable effect?

Comment: @Marcus: 5000 is not a large number for a 3GHz processor but if you're worried, check for nullity instead of adding an empty handler.

Answer (score 1):

If your application calls ChangeStatus thousand times per second, maybe it would be a problem. But only profiler can prove this.

Comment: I agree that only a profiler can definitely tell if that's a performance problem. But I always found the practice of adding an empty event handler just to get around a check for null to be a hack. Then again, I write extremely performance-sensitive code, so my point of view might be a bit skewed.

Comment: @Pepor: Can't agree more. While it's very unlikely to matter performance-wise most of the time, this is just a hack IMO.